# Instagram Graph API - "Application does not have permission for this action"

Tags: android, kotlin, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to get user post list with post details in my android application, when i add my account as a tester account in meta developer console i get code, Sort lived token & long lived token but when i call for get user post detail that givin me responce like this.

I added instagram scope "username,media" & my equest url is

https://graph.instagram.com/v12.0/me?fields=username,media&access_token=$access_token$

In which instagram account i logged in that i have more than 500 post.

```
 "error": {
        "message": "Application does not have permission for this action",
        "type": "IGApiException",
        "code": 10,
        "fbtrace_id": "AbIQfW1F22zKM3kQuII6l83"
    }
```

If anyone have any solution please let me know.

Comment: are you trying to get other user posts?

Comment: There is some limitation in [instagram graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api#limitations) so if you want access Instagram consumer accounts (i.e., non-Business or non-Creator Instagram accounts) you should use [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api)

Comment: yes, i want to get logged in user all post.

Comment: If i used `Instagram Basic Display API` which url gave me user post list in responce.

Comment: check this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference)

Comment: I follow this `guide` but still get same error.

Comment: i access code, access_token & long lived access_token but when i triet to get userdata gave that error.

Comment: I got the responce of personal instagram account. Thank you for helping me. @bhavin

Comment: I'm Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to `Review Connection` between your facebook page and connected instagram account.
For that you have to go to your facebook page settings, then select `instagram`. There you will find Review connection option